# I can see my static ip was changed, how can happen that?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud, google

**Today I cannot enter my website and I have seen that the static ip has been changed.
How is this possible?**

Comment: If you want it to be fixed, you have to specifically set it up that way. Otherwise, it can change with an instance reboot etc. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have misconfigured the network in your VM due to leaving the defaults settings in the VM, that means that your ip is [ephemeral](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#ephemeraladdress). As comment above says, you have to [reserve a static external IP address.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address)

You can learn more information about how ip addresses work in Google Cloud platform in the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses).

I suggest to reserve a external static ip address, login into the VM through ssh and update the IP address in the webserver.